# List of each numbers not equal False working but on equal number its not working

Tags: haskell

Below I show the output. I gave a list of numbers if they are not equal then return False and its working correctly. But If the list of numbers equal then its not return True. Can you check this code?

```
la [] = True
la a =
      if ((head a )==head (tail a))
          then la (tail a)
          else False
```

**Output:**

```
Cw2016> la [1,2,2]
False
Cw2016> la [2,2,2]

Program error: pattern match failure: head []

Cw2016> la [2,2,3]
False
Cw2016> la [0,1,3]
False
Cw2016> la [0,0,3]
False
Cw2016> la [0,0,0]

Program error: pattern match failure: head []

Cw2016>
```

Comment: Step through the evaluation of `la[1]`.

Comment: `la (x:xs)` is easier to read since `head (x:xs) = x` and `tail (x:xs) = xs`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that in the second branch, you only know that the list has size at least 1 but you're looking for the second argument. I recommend you replace head and tail (which are partial functions) with a pattern matching:

```
la [] = True
la (x0:x1:xs) =
      if (x0 == x1)
          then la (x1:xs)
          else False
```

If you call ghc with -W, you'll get the warning that your patterns don't cover x:[]. You probably want to add this branch:

```
la (x0:[]) = True
```

In passing, you should simplify your expression:

```
      if (x0 == x1)
          then la (x1:xs)
          else False
```

to:

```
(x0 == x1) && la (x1:xs)
```

To get a bit more technical about your problem, the issue arises when `a = [x]` for some `x`. First, `head` and `tail` are defined as:

```
head (x:xs) = x
head [] = undefined

tail (x:xs) = xs
tail [] = undefined
```

Then, the expression `head (tail a)` evaluates as follows:

```
  head (tail a)
=  { value of a }
  head (tail (x:[]))
=  { first equation of tail }
  head []
=  { second equation of head }
  undefined
```

And this is why you get an error.